# click on element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know it might sound stupid but for some reason I`m having some weird problem.

so, I have a code in js which generate a table with a buttons I gave all buttons same class.

when I try to click on them and use jquery function to console.log something nothing happens.

```
$.each(data,function(i, d){
    $('#myTable tbody').append(`
        <tr>
            <td>${d.Date}</td>
            <td>${d.Name}</td>
            <td>${d.Score}</td>
            <td><button class='graphXY' data=${d.id}>View</button></td>
        </tr>`);
});
```

its inside ajax and the table generates good and each button gets class and data good.

now when I try to do

```
$(".graphXY").click(function(){
    console.log("hit");
})
```

basically nothing happens and for some reason I cant find the reason.

Comment: You need to attach the click function to an element that existed on DOM load - something like `$(#myTable').on('click', '.graphXY', function() {...`

Comment: You need to perform `event delegation`. Look that up. This has been answered thousands of times.

Comment: Tnx alot @IsmailFarooq

Answer (score 2):

The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist.

It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".graphXY", function(){
    console.log("hit");
})
```